# Using if/else statement to run a command in shell

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I wanted to run a command in shell (basically via ansible playbook), the condition is, if the ps status gives non zero exit code then it needs to run another command. I don't wanted to split this into two tasks, one to check the ps status and another to execute the command. Instead using if/else condition, can this be merged into a single task?

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep httpd
```

If the above command exits with non zero status, then I need to fire another command which is given below. How can I merge these two commands as one and include this as a single task?

```
nohup /root/scripts/httpd.sh start &
```

Comment: https://www.ansible.com/blog/shell-scripts-to-ansible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

This does what you want:

```
  tasks:
    - name: pser
      shell: ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd && echo found || nohup sleep 1000 &
```

**NOTE:** I'm using the command `sleep 1000` as a stand-in for your Apache daemon process, `httpd`.

#### Example Run

```
$ cat pb.yml
- name: Hello Ansible - quick start
  hosts: all
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: pser
      shell: ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd && echo found || nohup sleep 1000 &
```

Notice we have neither a sleep or httpd process present:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep -E "[s]leep|[h]ttpd"
$
```

Now we run the playbook:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml

PLAY [Hello Ansible - quick start] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pser] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Now we have a sleep process going:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep -E "[s]leep|[h]ttpd"
  501 34422     1   0  2:00AM ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash -c ps -ef | grep [h]ttpd && echo found || nohup sleep 1000 &
  501 34425 34422   0  2:00AM ttys000    0:00.00 sleep 1000
```

Now if we reset things and do the same thing but this time open up a edit window with a filename of `httpd` to "fake out" the `grep [h]ttpd`:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep -E "[s]leep|[h]ttpd"
  501 34542     1   0  2:02AM ??         0:00.27 /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/HEAD-4e631a0/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim -f -g httpd
```

Running the playbook this time will do nothing:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml

PLAY [Hello Ansible - quick start] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [pser] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Still just our edit window with the 'httpd' file open:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep -E "[s]leep|[h]ttpd"
  501 34542     1   0  2:02AM ??         0:00.27 /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/HEAD-4e631a0/MacVim.app/Contents/bin/../MacOS/Vim -f -g httpd
```